# Mantener los datos al pulsar flecha atrás del navegador PHP

Tags: php, post, get

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy en la **página A.php** y si quiero navegar mediante un botón a la **página B.php** funciona correctamente. El problema viene cuando de **B.php** quiero pasar a (pulsando la flecha atrás en el navegador) **A.php** **manteniendo los datos** que tenía en **A.php.**

¿Por qué, además de no mantenerse los datos, me muestra la siguiente página?

**Código que muestra al pulsar para atrás:**

```
Confirmar reenvío del formulario
Esta página web necesita los datos introducidos anteriormente para mostrarse correctamente. Puedes volver a enviar los datos, pero se repetirán las acciones que haya realizado la página.
Pulsa el botón de actualización de página para que se vuelvan a enviar los datos necesarios para cargar la página.
ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

Por ejemplo, envío los datos mediante formularios con método POST. ¿Es correcto?

Muestro código de, por ejemplo, la **página A.php** en mi caso:

```
<?php
    include_once "Clases/BD.php";

    //Iniciar una nueva sesión o reanudar la existente.
    session_start();

    //Si existe la sesión "cliente"..., la guardamos en una variable.
    if (isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
        $cliente = $_SESSION['cliente'];
    }

    //Si nos hemos salido de la sesión del administrador, destruimos la sesión.
    if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
       //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "administrador".
       unset($_SESSION["administrador"]);
       //session_destroy();
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculoNoches.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function() {
                var defaults = {
                    closeText: 'Cerrar', 
                    prevText: '<Anterior', 
                    nextText: 'Siguiente>', 
                    currentText: 'Hoy', 
                    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'], 
                    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'], 
                    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'], 
                    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'], 
                    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'], 
                    weekHeader: 'Sm', 
                    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', 
                    firstDay: 1, 
                    isRTL: false, 
                    showMonthAfterYear: false, 
                    yearSuffix: '' 
                }; 

                $.datepicker.setDefaults(defaults); 

                $("#check_in").datepicker({
                    minDate: 0, //The value "0" means today (0 days from today). 
                    onSelect: function(dateStr) { 
                        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //Día actual. 
                        if (minDate) { 
                            //Se comprueba si existe una fecha de salida.
                            var maxDate = $("#check_out").datepicker('getDate'); 
                            if (maxDate && minDate < maxDate) {
                                minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1);
                                $("#check_out").datepicker("option", "minDate", minDate);
                            } else { 
                                //Si existe una fecha de salida y es menor a la fecha de entrada.
                                minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1); 
                                //Se cambia la fecha al día siguiente del seleccionado en la fecha de entrada.
                                $('#check_out').datepicker('setDate', minDate). 
                                datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate); //Día siguiente al actual en "check_out". 
                            }
                        } 
                        $('#check_out').change(); //Activar el evento "onchange". 
                        $('#check_out').prop("disabled", false); //Se activa la fecha de salida.
                    } 
                }); 

                $('#check_out').datepicker().on("input click", function(e) { 
                    console.log("Fecha salida cambiada: ", e.target.value); 
                }); 
            });
        </script> 
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo1.jpg">
        <div class="sesion_cliente">
            <?php 
            //Si existe la sesión "cliente"...
            if(isset($_SESSION['cliente'])){
                echo "<p class='negrita'>Bienvenido <a href='menu_cliente.php?nueva=1#nueva'>".$cliente."</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;";
                echo "<a href='index.php?salir=1'>Salir</a></p>";
                //Si existe y hemos pulsado el link "Salir"...
                if(isset($_REQUEST["salir"])){
                    //Borramos o destruimos la sesión "cliente".
                    unset($_SESSION["cliente"]);
                    //Redireccionamos a la página "iniciar_sesion_cliente.php" en 0 segundos.
                    header("Refresh:0; url=iniciar_sesion_cliente.php");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>

        <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="busqueda">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">
                    <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
                    <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">
                    <!--<script type="text/javascript">
                    $("#check_in").blur(function(){
                        $(this).css("background-color", "#42F508");
                    });
                    </script>-->
                    <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>

                    <p id="calculoNoches"></p><br/>

                    <label for="personas"><b>Personas:</b></label>
                    <?php
                    echo "<select name='personas'>";
                        //Si la variable no existe, establecemos el valor por defecto. personas=2
                        if(!isset($_POST['personas'])){
                            $_POST['personas'] = 2;
                        }

                        for ($i=1; $i<11; $i++) {
                            if($i == $_POST['personas']){
                                echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                            }else{
                                echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                            }
                        }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>
                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- .a { margin-bottom:10px;}    .a + .b { margin-top: 4em;} -->

            <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "buscar"...
                if(isset($_POST["buscar"]) && $_POST["check_in"]!="" && $_POST["check_out"]!=""){
                    $check_in = $_POST["check_in"];
                    $check_out = $_POST["check_out"];
                    //Llamamos al método "obtenerCabanasPorFecha" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
                    $datos = BD::obtenerCabanasPorFecha($check_in, $check_out);
                    echo "<br/>";
                    foreach($datos as $cabana){
                        echo "<b><u><p class='titulo'>Coste de la cabaña <font color='red'>".$cabana->getNombre()."</font> por noche: ".$cabana->getPrecio()."€/noche</p></u></b><br/>";
                        $personas = $_POST["personas"];
                        //Calcular el número de noches entre dos fechas.
                        $check_in_analizar = new DateTime($check_in);
                        $check_out_analizar = new DateTime($check_out);
                        $resta = $check_in_analizar->diff($check_out_analizar);
                        $noches = $resta->format('%a');
                        //Mostramos al cliente el coste TOTAL y el coste "parcial" por persona.
                        $pago_total = $cabana->getPrecio()*$noches;
                        $pago_pax = $pago_total/$personas;

                        $_SESSION["pago_total"] = $pago_total;

                        echo "<b>".$personas." persona/s &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$noches." noche/s &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color='blue'>".$pago_total."€/total</font> (".round($pago_pax,2)."€/pax)"."</b>"; 
                        echo "<form action='confirmacion_reserva.php' method='POST' name='mireserva'>";
                            //Campos hidden (oculto) donde guardamos un valor que NO queremos mostrar.
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='idcabana' value='".$cabana->getIdcabana()."'/>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='check_in' value='".$check_in."'/>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='check_out' value='".$check_out."'/>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='personas' value='".$personas."'/>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' name='pago_total' value='".$pago_total."'/>";
                            echo "<center><input type='submit' name='reservar' value='Reservar'/></center>";
                        echo "</form>";
                        echo "<br/>";

                        //Cargamos las imágenes en un array $imagenes.
                        $imagenes = $cabana->getImagenes();
                        foreach($imagenes as $imagen){
                            echo "<img src='imagenes/".$imagen."' width='210' height='210'/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                        }
                        echo "<br/>";

                        //Cargamos la descripción de la cabaña.
                        echo "<b><font color='blue'>".$cabana->getDescripcion()."</font></p></b>";
                        echo "<br/>";

                        //Cargamos los accesorios de la cabaña en cuestión.
                        $objeto_accesorios = BD::obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana($cabana->getIdcabana());
                        $todos_accesorios = BD::todosAccesorios();
                        //echo '<div style="display:table">'; // Lo recogemos en un div
                        foreach($todos_accesorios as $objeto){
                            $existe = false;
                            foreach($objeto_accesorios as $columna){
                                //Si el accesorio global está en el accesorio de la cabaña, true.
                                if($objeto->getIdaccesorio() == $columna->getIdaccesorio()){
                                    $existe = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if($existe){
                                echo "<div style='float:left; width:20%; margin-bottom: 25px'>
                                    <img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' /><br/>
                                    <label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'>
                                        <input type='hidden' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]'><font size='2'>".$objeto->getDescripcion()."</font></label></div>";
                            }
                            $existe = false;        
                        }
                        //echo '</div>';
                        //http://librosweb.es/referencia/css/clear.html
                        echo "<div style='clear:both'></div>";

                        //Cargamos las opiniones de la cabaña.
                        $opiniones = BD::obtenerOpinionesPorCabana($cabana->getIdcabana());
                            if($opiniones == null){
                                //echo "<br/><div id='sin_opiniones'><h3>Aún no hay opiniones...</h3></div><br/>";
                            }else{
                                foreach ($opiniones as $comentario){
                                    $fecha = new DateTime($comentario["fecha"]);
                                    echo "<br/><div id='opiniones'>".$fecha->format ('d/m/Y')."(".$comentario["idemail"].") - ".$comentario["opinion"]."</div><br/>";
                                }
                            }
                        echo "<hr/>";
                        echo "<br/>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Muestro código de, por ejemplo, la **página B.php** en mi caso:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Formulario de Login - Cliente</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_iniciar_sesion.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo2.jpg">
        <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
            <h2>CLIENTE</h2>
            <h4>INICIAR SESIÓN</h4>
            <input type="text" placeholder="&#128272; Usuario" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1">
            <input type="password" placeholder="&#128272; Contraseña" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2">
            <div id="mensaje" align="center">
                <?php if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 'true'): ?>
                    <h4><p style="color:red;">¡Sus datos no son correctos!</p></h4>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="iniciar" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión"><br/>
                <p class="form-link">¿Aún no tienes una cuenta? <a href="registrar.php">Regístrate aquí</a></p><br/>
                <p class="form-link"><a href="recuperar_contrasena.php">He olvidado mi contraseña</a></p><br/><hr/><br/>
                <p class="form-link"><img src="imagenes/entrar.jpg" height="10px" width="10px" alt="invitado"/>&nbsp;<a href="index.php">Entrar como invitado</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Si en esta página B.php pulso la flecha para atrás del navegador para volver a A.php me sale la información del mensaje que puse anteriormente.
¿Por qué? ¿Una posible solución?**

Comment: En la pagina A que tantos datos tienes?

Comment: Los datos de A.php los tengo en un formulario y los envío (siempre por POST) a C.php (si el usuario está registrado),y si no está registrado, mando a B.php para que se loguee y poder seguir.

Comment: si quieres mantener los datos del formulario tienes dos opciones usar Cookies/Sesiones y leerlas o almacenarlas en base de datos, igual mantener los valores solo porque le de a la flecha de atras me parece inseguro

Comment: ¿Cuál sería lo más positivo? ¿El uso de cookies? Un ejemplo please...

Comment: para darte un ejemplo tienes que cambiar tu pregunta creo que es de muy baja calidad porque no dices nada en concreto

Comment: Editada la pregunta con nuevo código, el necesario para poder entenderlo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema viene por como mandas las variables, cuando envías los datos con tipo POST se mandan de una manera que procesa una solicitud de envío, intenta cambiando esta linea,

```
 <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="POST" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
```

por esta otra:

```
 <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="logueo_cliente.php" method="GET" class="form" onsubmit="return validar_iniciar_sesion_cliente();">
```

y deberás hacer los arreglos correspondientes.

el problema radica en que cuando pasas de **A** a **B** se mandan los datos de una manera que tu pagina recibe la información, pero al no estar "visuales o tangibles" ( por así decirlo ) cuando regresas, tu pagina no logra obtener los valores, cambiando de **POST** a **GET** lo que haces es mandar la información por URL facilitando a tu pagina obtener los valores de nuevo, puedes manejarlo así, o para solucionar tu problema podrías manejar una sesión con la información para mantenerla si cambias de pagina y cuando guardes la información podrías destruir esa información para cargar nueva de ser necesario, espero te sirva.

Comment: ¿Es decir tendría que cambiar en el formulario el method POST por el GET? Y en cada asignación del código que haga con $_POST cambiarla a $_GET o $_REQUEST

Comment: El problema lo tengo el pulsar para atrás... en la navegación entre páginas mediante botones o enlaces "a href" sí me funciona. El problema es pulsar "<-" (atrás) en el navegador.

Answer (score 0):

@omaza1990 respondiendo a tu pregunta ( soy el mismo @user9186623 ya pude configurar bien mi cuenta ). afirmativamente tienes que cambiar POST por el GET creo que es la solución mas sencilla. intentalo y dime que tal te fue! exito!